# How to make filters work even though there is no package field in console in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I have filter field, which works fine if all the package data is there.
but here there is no package field for some of the items. 
I need to filter based on the package name, but now i am getting error as

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'package_id' of undefined
```

Pipe.ts:

```
          if(user.package_detail.package_id) {
            if(parseInt(user.package_detail.package_id) !== parseInt(filter[field])) {
              return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because for some datas, `user.package_detail` is undefined.

Change this:

```
if(user.package_detail.package_id) { ... }
```

To:

```
if(user.package_detail && user.package_detail.package_id) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i will check and update you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with package_detail.

```
if(user.package_detail && user.package_detail.package_id)
```

Comment: Obviously, we all posted the same answer at the same time :/

Comment: please, consider accepting one of the answers, so others who find this may know what works.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply ignore them this way :

```
if(user.package_detail && user.package_detail.package_id) {
   // no undefined package_detail or package_id here
}
```